# Styling hyperlinks in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView displaying some content that contains links. UIWebView automatically detects these and highlights/underlines them. Is there a way to change the styling? I'd like to choose a different color/set some CSS to be applied to all links.

I can modify the HTML on the fly when it loads by modifying the string but being able to change it via JS would be ideal as I'm already doing that for fonts (e.g. document.body.style.fontFamily = 'my font').

Answer (score 2):

You can style the links inside the page using simple CSS standard rules. To remove the underline and change the color of a link to, for example, red, add the following CSS style:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
```

The `UIWebView` had some specific styles that can be manipulated using non-standard CSS properties. You can find a complete list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions).

If you need to apply this style to a HTML page you did not control, you need to inject JavaScript code to the target page from your native Objective-C code.

So, first of all, let's write the JavaScript code that change the style of a `<a>` element with `id` "urlID":

```
var link = window.document.getElementById('urlId');
link.style['text-decoration'] = 'none'; 
link.style.color = 'red';
```

Then, we need to tell to the native `UIWebView` to execute this JavaScript code when the web page finished to load (in this way we are sure that the DOM element we are searching are there). 
To do so, we can use the UIWebView `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and its method [`webViewDidFinishLoad:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad:)

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *javaScriptCodeToExecute = @"var link = window.document.getElementById('urlId'); link.style['text-decoration'] = 'none'; link.style.color = 'red';";
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScriptCodeToExecute];
}
```

I put the JavaScript code inside the string variable `javaScriptCodeToExecute` and I told to the `UIWebView` to execute it using the [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) method.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I inject this into a page I don't control? e.g. I'm loading  google.com in a UIWebView and want to style the links.

Comment: Hi. Just added the explanation on how to inject custom JavaScript code inside an external web page loaded in a UIWebView. Let me know what do you think.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to be working either. Non links are turning red and links still have the same styling. I think it may be because Apple does link detection after the web view loads and is therefore overriding our styling.

Comment: You can check it using Safari developer console and see which CSS styles are applied to the links and in which order.

Comment: Works great. The only solution that worked for me, and I tried many. Do not forget to tag the id with every link.